# Decoding a codable tree of generic classes in Swift 4

Tags: ios, generics, swift4, codable, decodable

## Goals

I need a representation of generic objects interconnected in a tree like manner. This tree and their objects should have the following characteristics:

- It should be possible to build a tree out of 3 parts: **trunk**, **branch** and **apple**

  - where it's not possible to add a parent to a **trunk**
  - where a **trunk** can only get multiple **branch** nodes as child elements
  - where a **branch** can only have multiple **apple** nodes as child elements
  - where a **branch** can only have a parent of type **trunk** or **branch**
  - where it's not possible to add a child element to an **apple**
  - checks for a valid configuration should be at compile time >> using generics
- It should be codable by implementing the `Codable` protocol

  - so it can be encoded into a JSON
  - and decoded from a JSON

As an example at the end of this question I created a playground that fulfills all requirements but one:
***decoding the tree from a JSON***

## Explanation of the example code

A tree consists of nodes, in this case `TreePartNode`s, which are implementing the `TreePartNodeBase` protocol. 
The tree in this example is an array of `AnyTreePartNode`s that are also implementing the `TreePartNodeBase` protocol and wrapping an object implementing the `TreePartNodeBase` protocol that should be a generic `TreePartNode` (`TreePartNode<Trunk>`, `TreePartNode<Branch>` or `TreePartNode<Apple>`).

A `TreePartNode` has the property `treePart` of type `AnyTreePart`. `AnyTreePart` (similar to `AnyTreePartNode`) wraps an object that implements the `TreePart` protocol (`Trunk`, `Branch` or `Apple`).

All these classes are implementing `Codable` and `Equatable`.

## Code ready for pasting inside a Xcode playground

```
import Foundation

///////////// TreePart -> implemented by Trunk, Branch, Apple and AnyTreePart

protocol TreePart: Codable {
    var name: String { get set }

    func isEqualTo( _ other: TreePart ) -> Bool

    func asEquatable() -> AnyTreePart
}

extension TreePart where Self: Equatable {

    func isEqualTo( _ other: TreePart ) -> Bool {
        guard let otherTreePart = other as? Self else { return false }

        return self == otherTreePart
    }

    func asEquatable() -> AnyTreePart {
        return AnyTreePart( self )
    }
}

///////////// AnyTreePart -> wrapper for Trunk, Branch and Apple

class AnyTreePart: TreePart, Codable {

    var wrappedTreePart: TreePart

    var name: String {
        get {
            return self.wrappedTreePart.name
        }
        set {
            self.wrappedTreePart.name = newValue
        }
    }

    init( _ treePart: TreePart ) {
        self.wrappedTreePart = treePart
    }

    // MARK: Codable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case trunk,
             branch,
             apple
    }

    required convenience init( from decoder: Decoder ) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self )

        var treePart: TreePart?

        if let trunk = try container.decodeIfPresent( Trunk.self, forKey: .trunk ) {
            treePart = trunk
        }

        if let branch = try container.decodeIfPresent( Branch.self, forKey: .branch ) {
            treePart = branch
        }

        if let apple = try container.decodeIfPresent( Apple.self, forKey: .apple ) {
            treePart = apple
        }

        guard let foundTreePart = treePart else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context( codingPath: [CodingKeys.trunk, CodingKeys.branch, CodingKeys.apple], debugDescription: "Could not find the treePart key" )
            throw DecodingError.keyNotFound( CodingKeys.trunk, context )
        }

        self.init( foundTreePart )
    }

    func encode( to encoder: Encoder ) throws {
        var container = encoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self )

        switch self.wrappedTreePart {

        case let trunk as Trunk:
            try container.encode( trunk, forKey: .trunk )

        case let branch as Branch:
            try container.encode( branch, forKey: .branch )

        case let apple as Apple:
            try container.encode( apple, forKey: .apple )

        default:
            fatalError( "Encoding error: No encoding implementation for \( type( of: self.wrappedTreePart ) )" )
        }
    }

}

extension AnyTreePart: Equatable {
    static func ==( lhs: AnyTreePart, rhs: AnyTreePart ) -> Bool {
        return lhs.wrappedTreePart.isEqualTo( rhs.wrappedTreePart )
    }
}

///////////// TreePartNodeBase -> implemented by TreePartNode<T: TreePart> and AnyTreePartNode

protocol TreePartNodeBase: class {

    var treePart: AnyTreePart { get set }

    var uuid: UUID { get }

    var parent: AnyTreePartNode? { get set }

    var weakChildren: NSPointerArray { get }

    func isEqualTo( _ other: TreePartNodeBase ) -> Bool

    func asEquatable() -> AnyTreePartNode
}

extension TreePartNodeBase where Self: Equatable {

    func isEqualTo( _ other: TreePartNodeBase ) -> Bool {
        guard let otherTreePartNode = other as? Self else { return false }

        return self == otherTreePartNode &&
               self.treePart == other.treePart &&
               self.uuid == other.uuid &&
               self.parent == other.parent &&
               self.children == other.children
    }

    func asEquatable() -> AnyTreePartNode {
        return AnyTreePartNode( self )
    }
}

extension TreePartNodeBase {
    var children: [AnyTreePartNode] {
        guard let allNodes = self.weakChildren.allObjects as? [AnyTreePartNode] else {
            fatalError( "The children nodes are not of type \( type( of: AnyTreePartNode.self ) )" )
        }

        return allNodes
    }
}

///////////// AnyTreePartNode -> wrapper of TreePartNode<T: TreePart>

class AnyTreePartNode: TreePartNodeBase, Codable {
    unowned var wrappedTreePartNode: TreePartNodeBase

    var treePart: AnyTreePart {
        get {
            return self.wrappedTreePartNode.treePart
        }
        set {
            self.wrappedTreePartNode.treePart = newValue
        }
    }

    var uuid:                  UUID {
        return self.wrappedTreePartNode.uuid
    }

    /// The parent node
    weak var parent: AnyTreePartNode? {
        get {
            return self.wrappedTreePartNode.parent
        }
        set {
            self.wrappedTreePartNode.parent = newValue
        }
    }

    /// The weak references to the children of this node
    var weakChildren: NSPointerArray {
        return self.wrappedTreePartNode.weakChildren
    }

    init( _ treePartNode: TreePartNodeBase ) {
        self.wrappedTreePartNode = treePartNode
    }

    // MARK: Codable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case trunkNode,
             branchNode,
             appleNode
    }

    required convenience init( from decoder: Decoder ) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self )
        // even if an empty Trunk is created, the decoder crashes
        self.init( TreePartNode<Trunk>( Trunk() ) )            

        // This attempt of decoding possible nodes doesn't work
        /*
        if let trunkNode: TreePartNode<Trunk> = try container
              .decodeIfPresent( TreePartNode<Trunk>.self, forKey: .trunkNode ) {
            self.init( trunkNode )

        } else if let branchNode: TreePartNode<Branch> = try container
              .decodeIfPresent( TreePartNode<Branch>.self, forKey: .branchNode ) {
            self.init( branchNode )

        } else if let appleNode: TreePartNode<Apple> = try cont«ainer
              .decodeIfPresent( TreePartNode<Apple>.self, forKey: .appleNode ) {
            self.init( appleNode )

        } else {
                let context = DecodingError.Context( codingPath: [CodingKeys.trunkNode,
                                                                                                                    CodingKeys.branchNode,
                                                                                                                    CodingKeys.appleNode],
                                                                                         debugDescription: "Could not find the treePart node key" )
                throw DecodingError.keyNotFound( CodingKeys.trunkNode, context )
        }
        */

       // TODO recreating the connections between the nodes should happen after all objects are decoded and will be done based on the UUIDs
    }

    func encode( to encoder: Encoder ) throws {
        var container = encoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self )

        switch self.wrappedTreePartNode {

        case let trunkNode as TreePartNode<Trunk>:
            try container.encode( trunkNode, forKey: .trunkNode )

        case let branchNode as TreePartNode<Branch>:
            try container.encode( branchNode, forKey: .branchNode )

        case let appleNode as TreePartNode<Apple>:
            try container.encode( appleNode, forKey: .appleNode )

        default:
            fatalError( "Encoding error: No encoding implementation for \( type( of: self.wrappedTreePartNode ) )" )
        }
    }
}

extension AnyTreePartNode: Equatable {
    static func ==( lhs: AnyTreePartNode, rhs: AnyTreePartNode ) -> Bool {
        return lhs.wrappedTreePartNode.isEqualTo( rhs.wrappedTreePartNode )
    }
}

// enables printing of the wrapped tree part and its child elements
extension AnyTreePartNode: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var text = "\( type( of: self.wrappedTreePartNode.treePart.wrappedTreePart ))"

        if !self.children.isEmpty {
            text += " { " + self.children.map { $0.description }.joined( separator: ", " ) + " }"
        }
        return text
    }
}

///////////// TreeParts (Trunk, Branch and Apple)

class Trunk: TreePart, Codable, Equatable {
    var name: String

    var color: String

    init( name: String = "trunk",
              color: String = "#CCC" ) {
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Trunk, rhs: Trunk) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name &&
                     lhs.color == rhs.color
    }
}

class Branch: TreePart, Codable, Equatable {
    var name: String

    var length: Int

    init( name: String = "branch",
                length: Int = 4 ) {
        self.name = name
        self.length = length
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Branch, rhs: Branch) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name &&
                     lhs.length == rhs.length
    }
}

class Apple: TreePart, Codable, Equatable {
    var name: String

    var size: Int

    init( name: String = "apple",
                size: Int = 2 ) {
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Apple, rhs: Apple) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name &&
                     lhs.size == rhs.size
    }
}

///////////// TreePartNode -> The node in the tree that contains the TreePart

class TreePartNode<T: TreePart>: TreePartNodeBase, Codable {

    var equatableSelf: AnyTreePartNode!

    var uuid: UUID

    var treePart: AnyTreePart

    var weakChildren = NSPointerArray.weakObjects()

    private var parentUuid : UUID?

    private var childrenUuids : [UUID]?

    weak var parent: AnyTreePartNode? {
        willSet {
            if newValue == nil {
                // unrelated code
                // ... removes the references to this object in the parent node, if it exists
            }
        }
    }

    init( _ treePart: AnyTreePart,
                uuid: UUID = UUID() ) {
        self.treePart = treePart
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.equatableSelf = self.asEquatable()
    }

    convenience init( _ treePart: T,
                uuid: UUID = UUID() ) {
        self.init( treePart.asEquatable(),
                             uuid: uuid )
    }

    init( _ treePart: AnyTreePart,
                uuid: UUID,
                parentUuid: UUID?,
                childrenUuids: [UUID]?) {

        self.treePart = treePart
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.parentUuid = parentUuid
        self.childrenUuids = childrenUuids
        self.equatableSelf = self.asEquatable()
    }

    private func add( child: AnyTreePartNode ) {
        child.parent = self.equatableSelf
        self.weakChildren.addObject( child )
    }

    private func set( parent: AnyTreePartNode ) {
        self.parent = parent
        parent.weakChildren.addObject( self.equatableSelf )
    }

    // MARK: Codable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case treePart,
             uuid,
             parent,
             children,
             parentPort
    }

    required convenience init( from decoder: Decoder ) throws {
        let container         = try decoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self )

        // non-optional values
        let uuid:   UUID      = try container.decode( UUID.self, forKey: .uuid )
        let treePart: AnyTreePart = try container.decode( AnyTreePart.self, forKey: .treePart )

        // optional values
        let childrenUuids: [UUID]?     = try container.decodeIfPresent( [UUID].self, forKey: .children )
        let parentUuid:    UUID?       = try container.decodeIfPresent( UUID.self, forKey: .parent )

        self.init( treePart,
                             uuid: uuid,
                             parentUuid: parentUuid,
                             childrenUuids: childrenUuids)
    }

    func encode( to encoder: Encoder ) throws {
        var container = encoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self )

        // non-optional values
        try container.encode( self.treePart, forKey: .treePart )
        try container.encode( self.uuid, forKey: .uuid )

        // optional values
        if !self.children.isEmpty {
            try container.encode( self.children.map { $0.uuid }, forKey: .children )
        }

        try container.encodeIfPresent( self.parent?.uuid, forKey: .parent )
    }
}

extension TreePartNode: Equatable {
    static func ==( lhs: TreePartNode, rhs: TreePartNode ) -> Bool {
        return lhs.treePart == rhs.treePart &&
                     lhs.parent == rhs.parent &&
                     lhs.children == rhs.children
    }
}

// enables printing of the wrapped tree part and its child elements
extension TreePartNode: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var text = "\( type( of: self.treePart.wrappedTreePart ))"

        if !self.children.isEmpty {
            text += " { " + self.children.map { $0.description }.joined( separator: ", " ) + " }"
        }
        return text
    }
}

// MARK: functions for adding connections to other TreeParts for each specific TreePart type

extension TreePartNode where T: Trunk {
    func add( child branch: TreePartNode<Branch> ) {
        self.add( child: branch.equatableSelf )
    }
}

extension TreePartNode where T: Branch {
    func add( child apple: TreePartNode<Apple> ) {
        self.add( child: apple.equatableSelf )
    }

    func add( child branch: TreePartNode<Branch> ) {
        self.add( child: branch.equatableSelf )
    }

    func set( parent branch: TreePartNode<Branch> ) {
        self.set( parent: branch.equatableSelf )
    }

    func set( parent trunk: TreePartNode<Trunk> ) {
        self.set( parent: trunk.equatableSelf )
    }
}

extension TreePartNode where T: Apple {
    func set( parent branch: TreePartNode<Branch> ) {
        self.set( parent: branch.equatableSelf )
    }
}

////////////// Helper

extension NSPointerArray {

    func addObject( _ object: AnyObject? ) {
        guard let strongObject = object else { return }
        let pointer = Unmanaged.passUnretained( strongObject ).toOpaque()
        self.addPointer( pointer )
    }

}

////////////// Test (The actual usage of the implementation above)

let trunk = Trunk()
let branch1 = Branch()
let branch2 = Branch()
let branch3 = Branch()
let apple1 = Apple()
let apple2 = Apple()

let trunkNode = TreePartNode<Trunk>( trunk )
let branchNode1 = TreePartNode<Branch>( branch1 )
let branchNode2 = TreePartNode<Branch>( branch2 )
let branchNode3 = TreePartNode<Branch>( branch3 )
let appleNode1 = TreePartNode<Apple>( apple1 )
let appleNode2 = TreePartNode<Apple>( apple2 )

trunkNode.add( child: branchNode1 )
trunkNode.add( child: branchNode2 )
branchNode2.add( child: branchNode3 )
branchNode1.add( child: appleNode1 )
branchNode3.add( child: appleNode2 )

let tree = [trunkNode.equatableSelf,
            branchNode1.equatableSelf,
            branchNode2.equatableSelf,
            branchNode3.equatableSelf,
            appleNode1.equatableSelf,
            appleNode2.equatableSelf]

print( "expected result when printing the decoded trunk node: \(trunkNode)" )

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

encoder.outputFormatting = [.prettyPrinted, .sortedKeys]

// This is how the encoded tree looks like
let jsonTree = """
[
  {
    "trunkNode" : {
      "children" : [
        "399B35A7-3307-4EF6-8B4C-1B83A8F734CD",
        "60582654-13B9-40D0-8275-3C6649614069"
      ],
      "treePart" : {
        "trunk" : {
          "color" : "#CCC",
          "name" : "trunk"
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "55748AEB-271E-4560-9EE8-F00C670C8896"
    }
  },
  {
    "branchNode" : {
      "children" : [
        "0349C0DF-FE58-4D8E-AA72-7466749EB1D6"
      ],
      "parent" : "55748AEB-271E-4560-9EE8-F00C670C8896",
      "treePart" : {
        "branch" : {
          "length" : 4,
          "name" : "branch"
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "399B35A7-3307-4EF6-8B4C-1B83A8F734CD"
    }
  },
  {
    "branchNode" : {
      "children" : [
        "6DB14BD5-3E4A-40C4-8EBF-FBD3CC6050C7"
      ],
      "parent" : "55748AEB-271E-4560-9EE8-F00C670C8896",
      "treePart" : {
        "branch" : {
          "length" : 4,
          "name" : "branch"
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "60582654-13B9-40D0-8275-3C6649614069"
    }
  },
  {
    "branchNode" : {
      "children" : [
        "9FCCDBF6-27A7-4E21-8681-5F3E63330504"
      ],
      "parent" : "60582654-13B9-40D0-8275-3C6649614069",
      "treePart" : {
        "branch" : {
          "length" : 4,
          "name" : "branch"
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "6DB14BD5-3E4A-40C4-8EBF-FBD3CC6050C7"
    }
  },
  {
    "appleNode" : {
      "parent" : "399B35A7-3307-4EF6-8B4C-1B83A8F734CD",
      "treePart" : {
        "apple" : {
          "name" : "apple",
          "size" : 2
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "0349C0DF-FE58-4D8E-AA72-7466749EB1D6"
    }
  },
  {
    "appleNode" : {
      "parent" : "6DB14BD5-3E4A-40C4-8EBF-FBD3CC6050C7",
      "treePart" : {
        "apple" : {
          "name" : "apple",
          "size" : 2
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "9FCCDBF6-27A7-4E21-8681-5F3E63330504"
    }
  }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    print( "begin decoding" )
    /* This currently produces an error: Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT. The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
    let decodedTree = try decoder.decode( [AnyTreePartNode].self, from: jsonTree )
    print( decodedTree.first( where: { $0.wrappedTreePartNode.treePart.wrappedTreePart is Trunk } )! )
    */
} catch let error {
    print( error )
}
```

How the decode function in `AnyTreePartNode` should decode the JSON? What am I missing?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @MikeTaverne I added the error message from playground as a comment at the end. But I don't think, this is helpful.

Comment: are you getting "Truck" as a resultant while decoding ?

Comment: @MAhipalSingh no, even if a call `self.init( TreePartNode<Trunk>( Trunk() ) )` inside the decoder init, the error appears in the line, where the JSON is decoded (at the bottom).

Comment: @SebKas, I'm getting    --> expected result when printing the decoded trunk node: Trunk { Branch { Apple }, Branch { Branch { Apple } } }
begin decoding
[Trunk, Branch, Branch, Branch, Apple, Apple]

Comment: @MAhipalSingh did you just uncomment my `if else` block in `AnyTreePartNode.init( from decoder: Decoder )`? I'm still getting a compile error when I do this. Did you change something else?

Comment: @SebKas yes i uncomment your code. i'm pasting code i had tried pls wait .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have change just remove `unowned` from `unowned var wrappedTreePartNode: TreePartNodeBase` line 
and compiled same code.

**RESULT:**

expected result when printing the decoded trunk node: Trunk { Branch { Apple }, Branch { Branch { Apple } } }
begin decoding
[Trunk, Branch, Branch, Branch, Apple, Apple]

**Code:**

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TestDrive
//
//  Created by Mahipal on 25/04/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Vandana. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        ////////////// Test (The actual usage of the implementation above)

        let trunk = Trunk()
        let branch1 = Branch()
        let branch2 = Branch()
        let branch3 = Branch()
        let apple1 = Apple()
        let apple2 = Apple()

        let trunkNode = TreePartNode<Trunk>( trunk )
        let branchNode1 = TreePartNode<Branch>( branch1 )
        let branchNode2 = TreePartNode<Branch>( branch2 )
        let branchNode3 = TreePartNode<Branch>( branch3 )
        let appleNode1 = TreePartNode<Apple>( apple1 )
        let appleNode2 = TreePartNode<Apple>( apple2 )

        trunkNode.add( child: branchNode1 )
        trunkNode.add( child: branchNode2 )
        branchNode2.add( child: branchNode3 )
        branchNode1.add( child: appleNode1 )
        branchNode3.add( child: appleNode2 )

        let tree = [trunkNode.equatableSelf,
                    branchNode1.equatableSelf,
                    branchNode2.equatableSelf,
                    branchNode3.equatableSelf,
                    appleNode1.equatableSelf,
                    appleNode2.equatableSelf]

        print( "expected result when printing the decoded trunk node: \(trunkNode)" )

        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        encoder.outputFormatting = [.prettyPrinted, .sortedKeys]

        // This is how the encoded tree looks like
        let jsonTree = """
[
  {
    "trunkNode" : {
      "children" : [
        "399B35A7-3307-4EF6-8B4C-1B83A8F734CD",
        "60582654-13B9-40D0-8275-3C6649614069"
      ],
      "treePart" : {
        "trunk" : {
          "color" : "#CCC",
          "name" : "trunk"
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "55748AEB-271E-4560-9EE8-F00C670C8896"
    }
  },
  {
    "branchNode" : {
      "children" : [
        "0349C0DF-FE58-4D8E-AA72-7466749EB1D6"
      ],
      "parent" : "55748AEB-271E-4560-9EE8-F00C670C8896",
      "treePart" : {
        "branch" : {
          "length" : 4,
          "name" : "branch"
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "399B35A7-3307-4EF6-8B4C-1B83A8F734CD"
    }
  },
  {
    "branchNode" : {
      "children" : [
        "6DB14BD5-3E4A-40C4-8EBF-FBD3CC6050C7"
      ],
      "parent" : "55748AEB-271E-4560-9EE8-F00C670C8896",
      "treePart" : {
        "branch" : {
          "length" : 4,
          "name" : "branch"
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "60582654-13B9-40D0-8275-3C6649614069"
    }
  },
  {
    "branchNode" : {
      "children" : [
        "9FCCDBF6-27A7-4E21-8681-5F3E63330504"
      ],
      "parent" : "60582654-13B9-40D0-8275-3C6649614069",
      "treePart" : {
        "branch" : {
          "length" : 4,
          "name" : "branch"
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "6DB14BD5-3E4A-40C4-8EBF-FBD3CC6050C7"
    }
  },
  {
    "appleNode" : {
      "parent" : "399B35A7-3307-4EF6-8B4C-1B83A8F734CD",
      "treePart" : {
        "apple" : {
          "name" : "apple",
          "size" : 2
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "0349C0DF-FE58-4D8E-AA72-7466749EB1D6"
    }
  },
  {
    "appleNode" : {
      "parent" : "6DB14BD5-3E4A-40C4-8EBF-FBD3CC6050C7",
      "treePart" : {
        "apple" : {
          "name" : "apple",
          "size" : 2
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "9FCCDBF6-27A7-4E21-8681-5F3E63330504"
    }
  }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

        do {
            print( "begin decoding" )
            // This currently produces an error: Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT. The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
             let decodedTree = try decoder.decode( [AnyTreePartNode].self, from: jsonTree )
            print( decodedTree )

        } catch let error {
            print( error )
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

import Foundation

///////////// TreePart -> implemented by Trunk, Branch, Apple and AnyTreePart

protocol TreePart: Codable {
    var name: String { get set }

    func isEqualTo( _ other: TreePart ) -> Bool

    func asEquatable() -> AnyTreePart
}

extension TreePart where Self: Equatable {

    func isEqualTo( _ other: TreePart ) -> Bool {
        guard let otherTreePart = other as? Self else { return false }

        return self == otherTreePart
    }

    func asEquatable() -> AnyTreePart {
        return AnyTreePart( self )
    }
}

///////////// AnyTreePart -> wrapper for Trunk, Branch and Apple

class AnyTreePart: TreePart, Codable {

    var wrappedTreePart: TreePart

    var name: String {
        get {
            return self.wrappedTreePart.name
        }
        set {
            self.wrappedTreePart.name = newValue
        }
    }

    init( _ treePart: TreePart ) {
        self.wrappedTreePart = treePart
    }

    // MARK: Codable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case trunk,
        branch,
        apple
    }

    required convenience init( from decoder: Decoder ) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self )

        var treePart: TreePart?

        if let trunk = try container.decodeIfPresent( Trunk.self, forKey: .trunk ) {
            treePart = trunk
        }

        if let branch = try container.decodeIfPresent( Branch.self, forKey: .branch ) {
            treePart = branch
        }

        if let apple = try container.decodeIfPresent( Apple.self, forKey: .apple ) {
            treePart = apple
        }

        guard let foundTreePart = treePart else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context( codingPath: [CodingKeys.trunk, CodingKeys.branch, CodingKeys.apple], debugDescription: "Could not find the treePart key" )
            throw DecodingError.keyNotFound( CodingKeys.trunk, context )
        }

        self.init( foundTreePart )
    }

    func encode( to encoder: Encoder ) throws {
        var container = encoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self )

        switch self.wrappedTreePart {

        case let trunk as Trunk:
            try container.encode( trunk, forKey: .trunk )

        case let branch as Branch:
            try container.encode( branch, forKey: .branch )

        case let apple as Apple:
            try container.encode( apple, forKey: .apple )

        default:
            fatalError( "Encoding error: No encoding implementation for \( type( of: self.wrappedTreePart ) )" )
        }
    }

}

extension AnyTreePart: Equatable {
    static func ==( lhs: AnyTreePart, rhs: AnyTreePart ) -> Bool {
        return lhs.wrappedTreePart.isEqualTo( rhs.wrappedTreePart )
    }
}

///////////// TreePartNodeBase -> implemented by TreePartNode<T: TreePart> and AnyTreePartNode

protocol TreePartNodeBase: class {

    var treePart: AnyTreePart { get set }

    var uuid: UUID { get }

    var parent: AnyTreePartNode? { get set }

    var weakChildren: NSPointerArray { get }

    func isEqualTo( _ other: TreePartNodeBase ) -> Bool

    func asEquatable() -> AnyTreePartNode
}

extension TreePartNodeBase where Self: Equatable {

    func isEqualTo( _ other: TreePartNodeBase ) -> Bool {
        guard let otherTreePartNode = other as? Self else { return false }

        return self == otherTreePartNode &&
            self.treePart == other.treePart &&
            self.uuid == other.uuid &&
            self.parent == other.parent &&
            self.children == other.children
    }

    func asEquatable() -> AnyTreePartNode {
        return AnyTreePartNode( self )
    }
}

extension TreePartNodeBase {
    var children: [AnyTreePartNode] {
        guard let allNodes = self.weakChildren.allObjects as? [AnyTreePartNode] else {
            fatalError( "The children nodes are not of type \( type( of: AnyTreePartNode.self ) )" )
        }

        return allNodes
    }
}

///////////// AnyTreePartNode -> wrapper of TreePartNode<T: TreePart>

class AnyTreePartNode: TreePartNodeBase, Codable {
     var wrappedTreePartNode: TreePartNodeBase

    var treePart: AnyTreePart {
        get {
            return self.wrappedTreePartNode.treePart
        }
        set {
            self.wrappedTreePartNode.treePart = newValue
        }
    }

    var uuid:                  UUID {
        return self.wrappedTreePartNode.uuid
    }

    /// The parent node
    weak var parent: AnyTreePartNode? {
        get {
            return self.wrappedTreePartNode.parent
        }
        set {
            self.wrappedTreePartNode.parent = newValue
        }
    }

    /// The weak references to the children of this node
    var weakChildren: NSPointerArray {
        return self.wrappedTreePartNode.weakChildren
    }

    init( _ treePartNode: TreePartNodeBase ) {
        self.wrappedTreePartNode = treePartNode
    }

    // MARK: Codable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case trunkNode,
        branchNode,
        appleNode
    }

    required convenience init( from decoder: Decoder ) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        // This attempt of decoding possible nodes doesn't work

         if let trunkNode: TreePartNode<Trunk> = try container.decodeIfPresent( TreePartNode<Trunk>.self, forKey: .trunkNode ) {
         self.init( trunkNode )

         } else if let branchNode: TreePartNode<Branch> = try container
         .decodeIfPresent( TreePartNode<Branch>.self, forKey: .branchNode ) {
         self.init( branchNode )

         } else if let appleNode: TreePartNode<Apple> = try container
         .decodeIfPresent( TreePartNode<Apple>.self, forKey: .appleNode ) {
         self.init( appleNode )

         } else {
         let context = DecodingError.Context( codingPath: [CodingKeys.trunkNode,
         CodingKeys.branchNode,
         CodingKeys.appleNode],
         debugDescription: "Could not find the treePart node key" )
         throw DecodingError.keyNotFound( CodingKeys.trunkNode, context )
         }


        // TODO recreating the connections between the nodes should happen after all objects are decoded and will be done based on the UUIDs
    }

    func encode( to encoder: Encoder ) throws {
        var container = encoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self )

        switch self.wrappedTreePartNode {

        case let trunkNode as TreePartNode<Trunk>:
            try container.encode( trunkNode, forKey: .trunkNode )

        case let branchNode as TreePartNode<Branch>:
            try container.encode( branchNode, forKey: .branchNode )

        case let appleNode as TreePartNode<Apple>:
            try container.encode( appleNode, forKey: .appleNode )

        default:
            fatalError( "Encoding error: No encoding implementation for \( type( of: self.wrappedTreePartNode ) )" )
        }
    }
}

extension AnyTreePartNode: Equatable {
    static func ==( lhs: AnyTreePartNode, rhs: AnyTreePartNode ) -> Bool {
        return lhs.wrappedTreePartNode.isEqualTo( rhs.wrappedTreePartNode )
    }
}

// enables printing of the wrapped tree part and its child elements
extension AnyTreePartNode: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var text = "\( type( of: self.wrappedTreePartNode.treePart.wrappedTreePart ))"

        if !self.children.isEmpty {
            text += " { " + self.children.map { $0.description }.joined( separator: ", " ) + " }"
        }
        return text
    }
}

///////////// TreeParts (Trunk, Branch and Apple)

class Trunk: TreePart, Codable, Equatable {
    var name: String

    var color: String

    init( name: String = "trunk",
          color: String = "#CCC" ) {
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Trunk, rhs: Trunk) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name &&
            lhs.color == rhs.color
    }
}

class Branch: TreePart, Codable, Equatable {
    var name: String

    var length: Int

    init( name: String = "branch",
          length: Int = 4 ) {
        self.name = name
        self.length = length
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Branch, rhs: Branch) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name &&
            lhs.length == rhs.length
    }
}

class Apple: TreePart, Codable, Equatable {
    var name: String

    var size: Int

    init( name: String = "apple",
          size: Int = 2 ) {
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Apple, rhs: Apple) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name &&
            lhs.size == rhs.size
    }
}

///////////// TreePartNode -> The node in the tree that contains the TreePart

class TreePartNode<T: TreePart>: TreePartNodeBase, Codable {

    var equatableSelf: AnyTreePartNode!

    var uuid: UUID

    var treePart: AnyTreePart

    var weakChildren = NSPointerArray.weakObjects()

    private var parentUuid : UUID?

    private var childrenUuids : [UUID]?

    weak var parent: AnyTreePartNode? {
        willSet {
            if newValue == nil {
                // unrelated code
                // ... removes the references to this object in the parent node, if it exists
            }
        }
    }

    init( _ treePart: AnyTreePart,
          uuid: UUID = UUID() ) {
        self.treePart = treePart
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.equatableSelf = self.asEquatable()
    }

    convenience init( _ treePart: T,
                      uuid: UUID = UUID() ) {
        self.init( treePart.asEquatable(),
                   uuid: uuid )
    }

    init( _ treePart: AnyTreePart,
          uuid: UUID,
          parentUuid: UUID?,
          childrenUuids: [UUID]?) {

        self.treePart = treePart
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.parentUuid = parentUuid
        self.childrenUuids = childrenUuids
        self.equatableSelf = self.asEquatable()
    }

    private func add( child: AnyTreePartNode ) {
        child.parent = self.equatableSelf
        self.weakChildren.addObject( child )
    }

    private func set( parent: AnyTreePartNode ) {
        self.parent = parent
        parent.weakChildren.addObject( self.equatableSelf )
    }

    // MARK: Codable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case treePart,
        uuid,
        parent,
        children,
        parentPort
    }

    required convenience init( from decoder: Decoder ) throws {
        let container         = try decoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self )

        // non-optional values
        let uuid:   UUID      = try container.decode( UUID.self, forKey: .uuid )
        let treePart: AnyTreePart = try container.decode( AnyTreePart.self, forKey: .treePart )

        // optional values
        let childrenUuids: [UUID]?     = try container.decodeIfPresent( [UUID].self, forKey: .children )
        let parentUuid:    UUID?       = try container.decodeIfPresent( UUID.self, forKey: .parent )

        self.init( treePart,
                   uuid: uuid,
                   parentUuid: parentUuid,
                   childrenUuids: childrenUuids)
    }

    func encode( to encoder: Encoder ) throws {
        var container = encoder.container( keyedBy: CodingKeys.self )

        // non-optional values
        try container.encode( self.treePart, forKey: .treePart )
        try container.encode( self.uuid, forKey: .uuid )

        // optional values
        if !self.children.isEmpty {
            try container.encode( self.children.map { $0.uuid }, forKey: .children )
        }

        try container.encodeIfPresent( self.parent?.uuid, forKey: .parent )
    }
}

extension TreePartNode: Equatable {
    static func ==( lhs: TreePartNode, rhs: TreePartNode ) -> Bool {
        return lhs.treePart == rhs.treePart &&
            lhs.parent == rhs.parent &&
            lhs.children == rhs.children
    }
}

// enables printing of the wrapped tree part and its child elements
extension TreePartNode: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var text = "\( type( of: self.treePart.wrappedTreePart ))"

        if !self.children.isEmpty {
            text += " { " + self.children.map { $0.description }.joined( separator: ", " ) + " }"
        }
        return text
    }
}

// MARK: functions for adding connections to other TreeParts for each specific TreePart type

extension TreePartNode where T: Trunk {
    func add( child branch: TreePartNode<Branch> ) {
        self.add( child: branch.equatableSelf )
    }
}

extension TreePartNode where T: Branch {
    func add( child apple: TreePartNode<Apple> ) {
        self.add( child: apple.equatableSelf )
    }

    func add( child branch: TreePartNode<Branch> ) {
        self.add( child: branch.equatableSelf )
    }

    func set( parent branch: TreePartNode<Branch> ) {
        self.set( parent: branch.equatableSelf )
    }

    func set( parent trunk: TreePartNode<Trunk> ) {
        self.set( parent: trunk.equatableSelf )
    }
}

extension TreePartNode where T: Apple {
    func set( parent branch: TreePartNode<Branch> ) {
        self.set( parent: branch.equatableSelf )
    }
}

////////////// Helper

extension NSPointerArray {

    func addObject( _ object: AnyObject? ) {
        guard let strongObject = object else { return }
        let pointer = Unmanaged.passUnretained( strongObject ).toOpaque()
        self.addPointer( pointer )
    }

}
```

Comment: This works for this case. But wouldn't a strong reference to the wrapped `TreePartNode` create an unwanted memory leak? I mean if afterwards one `TreePartNode<Branch>` is deallocated (e.g. by setting it to `nil`), the `AnyTreePartNode` wrapper still exists, right?

Comment: @SebKas you need to remove wrapper object, when its not in use

Comment: I see, but this is really inconvenient. In the following example an added `Branch` is set to nil, but its `deinit` function is not called, because it's wrapper stil has a reference to it:

`trunkNode.add( child: branchNodeA )`
`trunkNode.add( child: branchNodeB )`

`branchNodeA = nil // deinit is not called` but with
`branchNodeA.equatableSelf = nil // deinit is called and object is removed from tree`

If there is no better solution, I guess I have to define a `remove()` function.